# Tab key is not working in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

Tab key is not working for abbreviation in visual studio code.I have tried lot.How can I fix the problem?I am frustrated.Thinking of using Bracket instead of visual studio code.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! It is a bit unclear what is the expected behavior and if you have changed any configuration to achieve what you expect. The default behavior for the `tab` key is (and should probably be) reserved for inserting a `tab` char and/or indentation. Code completion, which may be what you want for *abbreviation* is done with `Ctrl+Space`.

Comment: Do you want to indent using tabs instead of spaces or what is your expected outcome when pressing the tab key?

Answer (score 19):

In my case
Using (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>) return `Tab button` to its normal working status.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be asking about this setting:

> // Insert snippets when their prefix matches. Works best when
>   'quickSuggestions' aren't enabled.

```
  "editor.tabCompletion": true,
```

That is set to `false` by default, change it to `true`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't change any keyboard shortcut or something else. You should change the language mod right bottom on the editor. It was selected `javascript` by default. You should change with `Javascript React` after that this changes all emmets suggestions is working.[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Hasan, I've been looking everywhere and set every single setting on True but this ended up being the issue

Answer (score 3):

Pressing Ctrl+M did not disable the mode for me, however the right side of the bar along the bottom of vs-code shows `Tab Moves Focus` as enabled, which you can click to disable.

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio code version 1.33, go to *File > Preferences > Settings*  Search for tabcompletion and by default it is off, select on, that is it, you are done.